# Foreign Relationship Not view in key column

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2012

I have database table server called like  TP_Users and TP_Roles

```
 TP_Roles:

 Id         PK, int, not null
 Role_Name  varchar(200), null
 IsActive   bit, null


TP_Users:

 Id          PK, int, not null
 UserName    nvarchar(50), null
 UserEmail   nvarchar(50), null
 DisplayName nvarchar(50), null
 Password    nvarchar(50), null
 RoleId      FK, int, not null
 IsActive    bit, not null
 ClientId    int, null
```

I have seen column FK_key value Foreign Key Server database

```
       FK Name                     Parent table       name      column_id       Refrenced table   name1  column_id1
FK__Users_cop__RoleI__27AED5D5      TP_Users         RoleId        6               TP_Roles       Id         1

FK__Users_cop__RoleI__28A2FA0E      TP_Users         RoleId        6               TP_Roles       Id         1
```

I want create like this Relationship using foreign key in local used like

```
CREATE TABLE TP_USERS (
  ID int(11) NOT NULL,
  USER_NAME varchar(50),
  ROL_ID int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (ID),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_roles` FOREIGN KEY (`ROL_ID`) REFERENCES `TP_ROLES` (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

after that check view i can view only one Fk_name  value not  able to seen other one but  i can view two Fk_key name server database .  what is mistake i did ? please any one Guide me

Comment: Are you on MySQL or SQL Server? You can't be using both

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How To make Relationship Two table using Foreign Key?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38196181/how-to-make-relationship-two-table-using-foreign-key)

Comment: @RichBenner Using SQL Server

Comment: Rich Benner i am new sql server  i am not except answer expect some idea

Comment: You say that you can view only one FK_Name, how are you viewing this? Have you refreshed your tree view in SSMS?

Comment: database hosted server mylittleadmin.i can't able make backup. so created database after view table fields  in server . i can view two type Fk_name but local after make foreign key Query i view only one name Fk_name not two like server database

Comment: i view only keys under the table

Comment: Please check your question - and reverb it. I don't understand your Problem....
For the time being: I GUESS you wonder, why you see only one FK after creating a table but in your query (wherever this came from) you see two FK names? On first glance I would say, that These two FKs belong to two different tables (maybe same Name but different Schema).